# OCX attributes

Tags: ocx

I have an OCX for capturing images from scanner.. I want to run it in internet explorer 7 using  tag. This OSX has no guide or tutorial to know how to use it. All what i need is to know how to deal with this OCX, what is the attributes for this OCX, for example if this OSX finish the scanning process it must be a flag indication the finish scanning status, is there any way to know these flags and attributes for any OCX.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would open the DLL in visual studio and check the methods for the class. I think javascript's properties attribute doesn't work for OCX-components.
If you don't have VS there probably exists some free tools to check DLLs.